# How to implement Delegates in FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to implement Delegate methods for FileSystemWatcher?

I have a delegate method named myDelegate which I want to call inside the timer function OnElapsedTimer, I tried calling myDelegate to invoke, OnDeleted, but the second argument is giving an compilation error.  How can I pass FileSystemEventArgs in the delegate method?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Timers;

public class Watcher
{

  public delegate void myDelegae(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e);

  public static void Main()
  {        
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTimer);
    aTimer.Interval = 5000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    Run();
    while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
  }

  [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
  public static void Run()
  {
    string path = @"C:\\File";
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |  NotifyFilters.Attributes;

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName; 

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

  }

  private static void OnDeleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", e.FullPath);
  }

  private static void OnElapsedTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\File"))
    {
      //Invoke  OnDeleted here
        var fseArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted, @"C:\",  @"File");
        OnDeleted("C:\\File",fseArgs);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please post the compilation error text...it would help. thanks

Comment: The modified code seems working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to call `OnDelete(e)` inside `OnElapsedTimer()`, which of course fails because that `e` is of type `ElapsedEventArgs`, and not `FileSystemEventArgs`.

The way to make this work is to create your own `FileSystemEventArgs` object, and pass that to `OnDelete()`. There's nothing special about the class, it simply stores information relevant to the operation that was performed. In this case, you *know* what that operation is: The directory called "C:\File" has been deleted:

```
var fseArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted, @"C:\", @"File");
OnDeleted(fseArgs);
```

Note that you're almost certainly better off just listening in the `OnDelete()` handler itself; why reproduce functionality that already works?

Comment: It should be `new FileSystemEventArgs(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted, "C:\\", "File")`

Comment: @Ingenu Good point! Not sure why I would need to use the full namespace for `WatcherChangeTypes`, though; `FileSystemEventArgs` is in the same namespace, so either none or both :)

Comment: You don't. Your post preceded mine, it was a snippet from what I was writing. I removed part of one namespace but not the other.

Comment: Thanks to all, My requirement is if anybody deleted the watch folder I need to capture that event also. So I come with implementing delegates, but now learned that no need to call delegate, just i can call OnDelete

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of problems with this code...

1. you should not be directly invoking the ondeleted handler. if you need to execute common code, create a third shared method to call.
2. `Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.FullPath);` is missing the second argument {1}
3. why do you have  `while (Console.Read() != 'q');` twice?
4. it all compiled fine for me, which I assume means you are actually having a runtime error, which should be fixed by resolving the first point above.

Comment: it's not corrected enough. why is there a timer there? and why are you directly trying to invoke the ondelete? that's not your codes responsibility. the watcher is there for a reason. you are running into problems because you have incorrect coding everywhere.